# Supervisor / Unix Permission Denied to write in directory

Tags: python, unix, file-permissions, supervisord

When I run my program and try to create a file, I am getting the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/giri26/couponmonk_project/user_15_qr.png'
```

I run my program using `supervisor` and this is the `config` file:

```
[program:gunicorn-couponmonk]
directory = /home/giri26/couponmonk_project
command = /home/giri26/venv/py2.7/bin/python /home/giri26/venv/py2.7/bin/gunicorn --worker-class socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker __init__:app 
stdout_logfile = /var/log/gunicorn/couponmonk-std.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/gunicorn/couponmonk-err.log
user = newuser
```

I thought this `error` was referring to the `permissions` for `newuser` so I added `newuser` to the `group` `giri26`.

Running `groups newuser` results in:

```
newuser : giri26
```

The results of `ls -ld couponmonk_project/` is:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 giri26 giri26 4096 Jun 27 22:34 couponmonk_project/
```

I figured that as `newuser` is part of the group `giri26` and the `group` has `rwx` permissions, then I would be able to `write` and `create` files in the `couponmonk_project` folder.

Am I looking at this correctly?

Thanks for your help.

**NOTE**

The folder above has the following `permissions`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 giri26 giri26 4096 Jun 27 22:52 ../
```

Does this need to change perhaps?

**UPDATE**

As suggested below, I ran `strace` with `curl` but the `output` did not contain any instances of `EACESS`. There are 400+ lines in the `output` file so can't really post it all here. Is there anything else that I might look out for? ATM, I can't really tell what is relevant.

These lines appears a lot:

```
762   access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
762   open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
762   read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\r\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
762   fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14768, ...}) = 0
762   mmap(NULL, 2109696, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa0d731f000
762   mprotect(0x7fa0d7321000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
762   mmap(0x7fa0d7521000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fa0d7521000
762   close(3)
```

Also this appears towards the end of the output:

```
recvfrom(3, "HTTP/1.1 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERR"..., 16384, 0, NULL, NULL) = 10510
```

Comment: Did you restart supervisor after doing the group changes? They will not apply before.

Comment: @KlausD. Yep, I've tried this but still having the same issue.

Comment: Does the file already exist?  If so, what are its permissions?

Comment: @AndrewHenle The file doesn't exist. It is about to be created when the error occurs.

Comment: @Giri - What's your OS?  If Linux, try running the process under `strace -f -o /your/output/file/name your command` and look for a the system call that returns `EACCESS`.  That will tell you the exact system call that failed, which is more data than you have right now.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am running `Debian 7`. I updated my question above. Unfortunately, I couldn't see an instance of EACCESS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try and restart the actual machine after making the file permission changes.

If you are running this on a remote server, issue a command via the web host control panel to reboot the actual machine.

This should hopefully solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The line in your gunicorn configuration file

```
user = newuser
```

does appear to be the central problem. As is sorta shown by

```
$ id
uid=1001(msw) gid=1001(msw) groups=1001(msw),4(adm),8(mail) …
```

A user has one uid and one gid. All other groups listed are groups that you belong to but are not your gid. To change the gid you have to explicitly ask for it to be switched as in:

```
$ newgrp mail
$ id
uid=1001(msw) gid=8(mail) groups=1001(msw),4(adm),8(mail) …
```

does change my gid to one of my other groups. Unfortunately newuser probably now looks like:

```
 $ id
 uid=22(newuser) gid=22(newuser) groups=22(newuser), 455(giri26) …
```

and since newuser might never log in to a shell nor even have a password, there is no good place to run newgrp.

To fix it, you should make giri26 the gid of newuser by modifying `/etc/passwd`

```
newuser:x:22:22: …
```

becomes:

```
newuser:x:22:455: …
```

This could have effects on newuser's other files and directories, be wary.

Comment: Thanks @msw. I ran the commands in your response and got the following for `newuser`: `uid=1001(newuser) gid=1000(giri26) groups=1000(giri26)`.